# CRM form. Preset Field is not saved on after Clicking Save button

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am working on CRM 2011.
On **Form_onLoad** event I am **presetting** the value of a field.

```
mdg.PreSetField("address1_line1","Amsterdam");
```

but after clicking on **save** button  my field **address1_line1 is blank**.

To check I put a alert on **Form_onsave** function.

```
alert("address =" + (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line1").getValue()));
```

In alert,I get the value of address1_line1 field but **finally address1_line1 is blank**.

mdg.PresetField function is as follows

```
mdg.PreSetField = function(attributeName, value) {
    var attribute;
    if (attributeName.setSubmitMode) {
        attribute = attributeName;
    }
    else {
        attribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName);
    }

    attribute.setSubmitMode('never');
    attribute.setValue(value);
    attribute.addOnChange(function() {
        attribute.setSubmitMode('always');
    });
};
```

Comment: you need to post the code of your PreSetField function

Comment: i have added PresetField function in my question ..

Comment: @GuidoPreite .. Thanks your Q helped. When i looked into PreSetField  i found the error which i  have posted in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it..

in my custom **mdg.PresetField function** earlier code was

```
attribute.setSubmitMode('never');
```

I changed **never** to **always** and now it is working..

Answer (score 0):

```
mdg.PreSetField("address1_line1","Amsterdam");
```

This code is not part of the CRM JavaScript API so I assume it's a custom library?  Have you added this script to the list of webresources available on the form?  Also make sure it comes before the script you are trying to use it in.

Comment: yes,it's a custom library and library is added to webresource and Form_onLoad  is attached on load event and Form_onsave is attached on save event